# I can't seem to update my sourceforge project?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, sourceforge

I recently had to delete my local copy of a sourceforge project I've been working on, and then I cloned it to a local repo. I've been commiting, and it's said that I've been updating the repo (locally at least), but when I checked online the last commit was from a week ago (before I deleted my local repo). Any ideas on why this might have happened/how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you pushed your changes from local back up to the remote? what's the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: origin ssh://nostrer@germline.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/germline/germline (fetch)
origin ssh://nostrer@germline.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/germline/germline (push)

Comment: so have you tried `git push origin` to get your changes up to the remote?

Comment: yes, Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 310 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://nostrer@germline.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/germline/germline
   0ce4e6d..3673bfd  master -> master

Comment: the actual project is here: https://sourceforge.net/p/germline/code/ci/master/tree/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments in your question, it looks like 2 different repositories.

If you view the commits at this [germline summary page](http://germline.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=germline/germline;a=summary) you can see your recent commits as expected.

But this is germline.git.sourceforge.net, and your remote is pointing to that, but the sourceforge project you originally linked to is git.code.sf.net

Comment: yep that worked, thanks a lot! I just needed to link up to the proper repository.